# How to enable gps in Android

Tags: android, gps

How to open the gps in Android when it is closed to retrieve the current position.
I test two method

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

private void turnGPSOff(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

and this method

```
enaABLE GPS:
Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
DISABLE GPS:

Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

but when opening the gps by one of these methods is execute code recovery position, it displays

```
    Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
            "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: How do you call this method ? this is bad practice to enable GPS by code and it doen't ensure that GPS will be enable , this i hack trick

Answer (score 11):

You can't enable GPS for a user, what you can do is, if GPS s disabled, prompt the user with a message to ask him to enable GPS and send him to the settings to enable it

with this code :

```
Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
```

This is a more detailed code on how to do it

http://java-blog.kbsbng.com/2012/08/displaying-dialog-in-android-to-prompt.html

To get the location you do this

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  /*try to see if the location stored on android is close enough for you,and avoid rerequesting the location*/
    Location location =  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (location == null
            || location.getTime()
                    - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() > MAX_LAST_LOCATION_TIME)
    {

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TIME_INTERVAL, LOCATION_INTERVAL, yourLocationListener);

    }
    else
    {
        //do your handling if the last known location stored on android is enouh for you
    }
```

in yourLocationListener, you implement what to do when you get the location

Comment: but I want to retrieve the current position in the background every minute    ,and it is not possible for the request to activate each time gps!!!!  and is not possible to make the gps active for the whole time, it consumes a lot of load!!!

Comment: No thi is just for enabling it, you do it once, if the user doesn't have it enabled. I edited my answer to tell you how to get the location every minute

Comment: @Dany Y what if the location is already on, i mean this show every time whenever location on or off.

Comment: You can check with this code, (I didn't add it above to show only the code relevant to go to the GPS settings) :  `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`

Answer (score 0):

It's inappropiate to enable GPS from the code. You can't fo that.

There used to be an exploit that allowed the GPS to be turned on by an app with no special permissions. That exploit no longer exists as of 2.3 (in most ROMs).